# How to get a flattened object/string output in parquet/spark/scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an parquet object where the schema contains nested entries like the following:

```
{"id" : "1201", "name" : "satish", "age" : "25", "path":[{"x":1,"y":1},{"x":2,"y":2}]}
{"id" : "1202", "name" : "krishna", "age" : "28", "path":[{"x":1.23,"y":2.12},{"x":1.23,"y":2.12}]}
```

How can I make it such that using spark/scala that I can output the following where everything is "flattened" based on the path entry:

```
{"id" : "1201", "name" : "satish", "age" : "25", "x": 1, "y":1}
{"id" : "1201", "name" : "satish", "age" : "25", "x": 2, "y":2}
{"id" : "1202", "name" : "krishna", "age" : "28", "x":1,"y":1}
{"id" : "1202", "name" : "krishna", "age" : "28", "x":2,"y":2}
```

Like:

```
+---+----+------+-+--+
|age|id  |name  |x|y |
+---+----+------+--- +
|25 |1201|satish|1|1 |
|25 |1201|satish|1|2 |
+---+----+------+----+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is use `explode` function on `path` column of your `dataframe` when you have read your `parquet` file.

Lets when you read from your `parquet` file you have `dataframe` as

```
+---+----+------+--------------+
|age|id  |name  |path          |
+---+----+------+--------------+
|25 |1201|satish|[[1,1], [2,2]]|
+---+----+------+--------------+
```

Once you combine `withColumn` and `explode` functions as

```
dataframe.withColumn("path", explode($"path")).show(false)
```

You will have following output

```
+---+----+------+-----+
|age|id  |name  |path |
+---+----+------+-----+
|25 |1201|satish|[1,1]|
|25 |1201|satish|[2,2]|
+---+----+------+-----+
```

If you still want to separate `path` column into two separate columns try

```
val newdf = dataframe.withColumn("path", explode($"path"))
    newdf.withColumn("x", newdf("path.x"))
        .withColumn("y", newdf("path.x"))
        .drop("path").show(false)
```

Or you can just use a `select` query

```
newdf.select("age", "id", "name", "path.x", "path.y").show(false)
```

You should have final result as

```
+---+----+------+---+---+
|age|id  |name  |x  |y  |
+---+----+------+---+---+
|25 |1201|satish|1  |1  |
|25 |1201|satish|2  |2  |
+---+----+------+---+---+
```

I guess this is what you are looking for

Comment: Could you show an example of the syntax for this assuming I have a reference to the dataframe object? I have not used explode before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use explode and select to get the result

Example:

```
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("ParquetAppendMode")
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._


  val data1 = spark.read.json("explode.json")

  val result = data1.withColumn("path", explode($"path"))

  result.select("id", "name", "age", "path.x", "path.y").show()
```

Output:

```
+----+-------+---+----+----+
|  id|   name|age|   x|   y|
+----+-------+---+----+----+
|1201| satish| 25| 1.0| 1.0|
|1201| satish| 25| 2.0| 2.0|
|1202|krishna| 28|1.23|2.12|
|1202|krishna| 28|1.23|2.12|
+----+-------+---+----+----+
```